# htaccess rewrite rule for multi site css in subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

I have site with multiple domain names with my assets structure like this. Depending on the domain visited, I want to pick up the correct assets/css/domain folder.

[image]

In my index.php file I'm linking the css like this:

```
<link href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I'm trying to rewerite the path to excude the domain name but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting my 404 error on the server. Here is the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*)$ assets/css/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA] <---this rule is not being met
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your link uses an _absolute_ path (`/assets/css/styles.css`, as opposed to the relative path `assets/css/styles.css`) which might be an issue here depending on the base URL of that site. Also the location of that configuration file you posted is relevant.

Comment: The base url in my app ends with "/". Does this affect the rule?

Comment: No, it does not, it is irrelevant. Relevant is the base URL, so the path up to the "logic" of your site, for example up to that html path you took the link from.

Comment: I'm really at a lost here - any suggestions on updaing the RewriteRule to get this to work?

Comment: So you do not answer to simple questions but want an answer yourself? I ask those questions to get additional information from your which is missing in the question, you see?

Comment: The pattern `^assets/css/(.*)$` would also match on `assets/css/hostname/styles.css` again, meaning this would keep on rewriting and adding more `/hostname/hostname/hostname` to the path, until the internal rewrite limit is reached. Try and allow for only files, no folders at the end - `^assets/css/([^/]*)$`